# Is it possible to have a deferred app link in a facebook post?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api I created an app link for my Android app. The app link recognition also works perfectly when the app is already installed.

But when it's not installed I also want to be able to track the source of which the user came (clicking this app link), so I assumed that this should trigger the deferred deep link functionality from the facebook SDK. Unfortunately, this didn't happen.

So is there a way to track install sources from a standard (non-paid) facebook post with the facebook SDK?

Comment: please check if you can get activity logs through your sdk that have full details what shared

Comment: I have activity log. but as I said the deferred deep link functionality is not triggered at all.